# Phaser 3 update CPU usage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, phaser-framework

I am using phaser with react and vite.

I have my player movement logic inside my update function. I suspect that because phaser runs at 60fps, the else block is being called 60 times a second to stop player movement which I believe causes my CPU usage to go up intolerably high.

```
import Phaser from 'phaser'
import { CustomCursorKeys } from '../types/customCursorKeys';

export default class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  private cursors: CustomCursorKeys | null = null
  private player: Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite | null = null;
  private speed: number = 200
  constructor() {
    super('GameScene')
  }

    private resizeCamera() {
        // Responsively set camera size to window size
        const width = window.innerWidth;
        const height = window.innerHeight;
        this.cameras.main.setSize(width, height);
        this.cameras.main.setScroll(0, 0);
    }

    preload() {
        // Load spritesheet and tileset images
    this.load.spritesheet('sokoban', 'sprites/sokoban_tilesheet.png', {
            frameWidth: 64
        })
        this.load.image('tiles', 'maps/test_tiles.png')
        this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('tilemap', 'maps/groundtrees.json')
  }

  create() {
        // Create world map using tileset image
    const map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'tilemap' })
    const tileset = map.addTilesetImage('test_tiles', 'tiles')
    
        // Create map layers
    map.createLayer('ground', tileset)
    map.createLayer('trees', tileset)

        // Create player sprite and add physics
    this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(map.widthInPixels / 2, map.heightInPixels / 2, 'sokoban', 52);

        // Create player animations
        const createAnimation = (prefix: string, startFrame: number, endFrame: number) => {
            this.anims.create({
                key: `${prefix}-idle`,
                frames: [{ key: 'sokoban', frame: startFrame }],
                frameRate: 1
            })
            
            this.anims.create({
                key: `${prefix}-walk`,
                frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('sokoban', { start: startFrame, end: endFrame }),
                frameRate: 10,
                repeat: -1,
            })
        }

        createAnimation('down', 52, 54)
        createAnimation('up', 55, 57)
        createAnimation('left', 81, 83)
        createAnimation('right', 78, 80)

        // Set up cursor keys for player movement
        this.cursors = {
      ...this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys(),
      ...(this.input.keyboard.addKeys('W,S,A,D')),
    }
    
        // Set up camera to follow player and bound to map size
        this.cameras.main.setBounds(0, 0, map.widthInPixels, map.heightInPixels);
        this.resizeCamera();
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            this.resizeCamera();
        });
        this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.player);
  }

    update() {
        if(!this.cursors || !this.cursors.A || !this.cursors.D || !this.cursors.W || !this.cursors.S || !this.player){
            return
        }
        /*
         Check if arrow keys or WASD keys is down,
         Set player's velocity and movement,
         Play walk animation
        */
        if (this.cursors.left.isDown || this.cursors.A.isDown) {
            this.player.setVelocity(-this.speed, 0)
            this.player.play('left-walk', true)
        } 
        else if (this.cursors.right.isDown || this.cursors.D.isDown) {
            this.player.setVelocity(this.speed, 0)
            this.player.play('right-walk', true)
        } 
        else if (this.cursors.up.isDown || this.cursors.W.isDown) {
            this.player.setVelocity(0, -this.speed)
            this.player.play('up-walk', true)
        } 
        else if (this.cursors.down.isDown || this.cursors.S.isDown) {
            this.player.setVelocity(0, this.speed)
            this.player.play('down-walk', true)
        } 
        /*
         If no arrow key is pressed stop the player's movement,
         Get the key of the current animation being played,
         If an animation is currently playing,
         Get the direction from the animation key,
         Play the idle animation for the current direction
        */
        else {
            this.player?.setVelocity(0, 0)
            const key = this.player?.anims.currentAnim?.key
            if (key) {
                let direction = key?.split('-')[0]
                this.player?.play(`${direction}-idle`, true)
            }      
        }
    }

  destroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resizeCamera.bind(this))
  }
}
```

My config file

```
    import Phaser from 'phaser'
    import GameScene from './scenes/GameScene'
    
    const config = {
      type: Phaser.AUTO,
      parent: 'game-content',
      backgroundColor: '#123456',
      scale: {
        mode: Phaser.Scale.ScaleModes.RESIZE,
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
      },
      physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
          gravity: { y: 0, x: 0 },
        },
      },
      scene: [GameScene],
    }

    export default new Phaser.Game(config)
```

If I add a return right below the else block, my idle CPU usage based on Activity Monitor hovers around 60%. If I run the else block as is, I see it dip to 20%. I've seen all the phaser tutorials put the stop player movement logic similarly to the code above. Is there something I am doing wrong to cause a high CPU usage?

Comment: Have you looked at your browser's profiler to see where your game is spending its time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to say, beacuse typescript is transpiled to javascript, but I assume it could have to do with the over use of `?`. since this will be transpiled into `if/else` and `null` checks.

> **That said**, it could simply be the missing `true` in the line `` this.player.play(`${direction}-idle`, true) ``

Nevertheless you could also keep your code *"simpler"*, like this:

```
update() {
    // Just One Check 
    if(!this.cursors || !this.player){
        return
    }

    if (this.cursors.left.isDown || this.cursors.A.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocity(-this.speed, 0)
        this.player.play('left-walk', true)
    } 
    else if (this.cursors.right.isDown || this.cursors.D.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocity(this.speed, 0)
        this.player.play('right-walk', true)
    } 
    else if (this.cursors.up.isDown || this.cursors.W.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocity(0, -this.speed)
        this.player.play('up-walk', true)
    } 
    else if (this.cursors.down.isDown || this.cursors.S.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocity(0, this.speed)
        this.player.play('down-walk', true)
    }  else {
        this.player.setVelocity(0, 0)
        if (this.player.anims) {
            let direction = this.player.anims.currentAnim.key.split('-')[0]
            // don'T start it always again
            this.player.play(`${direction}-idle`, true)
        }      
    }
}
```

**Update - *(from the Comments)*:**

1. set the frameRate of the idle animation to a lower number something like `1-10`, default vaule is `24`
2. set in the `config` the `type` to Phaser.CANVAS. *(some features are not support in this mode, but the performance will improve and is less strain on the hardware)*

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and edited the original code in my question to implement it, but my fan still blows up while my CPU usage spikes.

I was trying to see how https://github.com/kevinshen56714/SkyOffice implemented their solution because my computer runs skyoffice just fine, but I can't seem to replicate it.

Comment: @dev_el you could try setting the `frameRate` of the idle animation to a lower number something like 1-10, default vaule is 24.

Comment: I've tried setting the idle frameRate to 1 but the CPU usage still spikes. As my macbook air 2017 fan starts blowing up even when running the default https://reactjsexample.com/minimal-phaser3-create-react-app-template/, I think my computer just underperforms.

Comment: @dev_el that could be. One last think I can think of, you could set in the `config` the `type` to `Phaser.CANVAS`. (some features are not support in this mode, but the performance will improve and is less strain on the hardware)

Comment: That works! I changed the code from Phaser.AUTO -> Phaser.CANVAS and my idle CPU hovers around 60 to 70%! If you include this in your answer, I'd be happy to accept it!

Comment: @dev_el I had alread included it, I always update my answer :) Thank you for your feedback and help on finding the solution.